# Sort array of documents with nested documents lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

I've the following array of documents with nested documents. I can sort this array using a specific field in the nested document using lodash library

```
[{
    foo: {
        attrb: true,
        attrb1: xxx
    },
    foo1: {
        field1: xxx,
        field2: xxxx
    },
    foo2: {
        data: 1334,
        data1: 354354
    }
},
{
    foo: {
        attrb1: xyz
    },
    foo1: {
        field1: xxx,
        field2: xxxx
    },
    foo2: {
        data: 1334,
        data1: 354354
    }
},
{
    foo: {
        attrb1: xzy
    },
    foo1: {
        field1: xxx,
        field2: xxxx
    },
    foo2: {
        data: 1334,
        data1: 354354
    }
}]
```

How can I sort this using the attrb: true field in the document foo from the array, using lodash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Lodash's [`sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy) function:

```js
const sorted = _.sortBy(data, 'foo.attrb');
```

But you don't need Lodash to do that. You can use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```js
const data = [{
    foo: {
        attrb: true
    }
},
{
    foo: {
    }
},
{
    foo: {
        attrb: true
    }
}];

const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => {
  return !!b.foo.attrb - !!a.foo.attrb;
});
console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, please note that only one document has the attrb:true remaining documents will not contain that attrb at all. Your solution is working only if all the documents has that attrb otherwise it is putting the documents with out that attrb at first. Lodash solution is not at all working though.

Comment: @AjaySrikanth You may need to add custom logic to the function passed to `sort` (I'm not sure what result you're looking for). I've edited my answer to account for `attrb` being `undefined`.

Comment: thank you so much, I've already made some changes to the code to handle undefined, but you solution looks much simpler than what I did.